# Find table of interrupts for Linux or Windows?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, interrupt

I recently began study asm, and faced a problem, that i can't find table of all interrupt's for linux or win. I looked in intel documentation, but don't find this info. So, how do you find table of all interrupts?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “table of all interrupts?”  Do you mean “list of system calls?”  Or do you actually mean hardware interrupts?

Comment: Do you mean what EAX values are valid for Linux `int 0x80`?  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html is the list of system calls, and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html describes the asm ABI.  Or just look in `asm/unistd.h`.  Generally the documentation assumes C callers but there are fixed rules for the asm ABI.  So you don't need an equivalent of Ralf Brown's Interrupt List for 16-bit BIOS / DOS / 3rd-party stuff. 
 (http://ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)

Comment: See also https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you canʼt find "table of all interrupts" without a real hardware start because it depends on ton of factors, including extension adapter set, exact chipset version, processor version, and so on.

Iʼd assume x86 as the context. It is defined by Intel that first 32 interrupt vectors (0-31) are for use by CPU itself - it can generate their invocation on internally defined exceptions. That would clash with old style (known from various IBM PC descriptions) that interrupts are assigned to 8-15, but, it is defined as OS task to reassign all conflicting interrupts when entering the protected mode. Then, interrupt controllers (nowadays, you can assume all them are at least APIC) are programmed to assign interrupt numbers of remained set to hardware that requires them. What numbers are assignable, depends on bus type and delivery manner:

- MSI (message signaled interrupt), MSI-X - the main techniques for PCI-E - are assigned by APIC programming, typically one number per device and role (some devices will emit multiple interrupt types);
- old line-based style (classic PCI) - up to 4 interrupt lines per bus; so there may be collision between numbers, and handlers shall iterate all possible devices. In classic designs of Pentium 1-3 times, they were assigned by BIOS to range 10-14 and then moved by OS to some upper range.

At the system I write this, interrupt numbers assigned to hardware are 36-62 with some gaps. 17 of them are used by `xhci_hcd`.

To sum up: for CPU interrupts, read the CPU doc. For others, assume dynamic assignment and find the current assignment in OS state using respective API.

Comment: Thank you :)  I was able to understand some.

Answer (score 0):

So, i wrote code for windows and thought, that linux has table or list with interrupt. But I was surprised when learned, that linux has only one interrupt (int 80h) and many syscalls. So, i can look syscalls here

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/constants/syscalls.md

Also syscalls division by type of processor and architecture of OS (x32 or x64). So, i should be use syscall and only one interrupt - int 80h.
I understood this and now I want to help others